# Only check one checkbox at a time for each loop

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to check only one checkbox at a time but the problem is I'm using loop to display my checkbox data. So for the whole loop it can only check one when using code below. The thing is that I want it to be able to check one for each loop.

```
{% for i in income %}
<tr>
  <td>Salary</td>
  <td>{{ i.description}}</td>
  <td>${{ i.amount }}</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="salary" value='{{ i.amount}}' name="formA" checked="checked" /></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="salary" value='{{ i.amount}}' name="formB" /></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input.salary').on('change', function() {
        $('input.salary').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
    });
</script>
```

How my code looks like:

[image: image description here]

How I want it to be:

[image]

Really appreciate if you guys could help me on this.

Comment: "Checked" would be depends upon something... Here you tell simply that one checkbox is checked.

Comment: have you think about grouped "radio" ...  you may organize radio groups the way you want to limit choices.